# Filter List View on publishing page by current navigation term?

Tags: 2013, list, list-view, publishing-page, managed-navigation

I'm currently trying to create a mostly dynamic intranet site using managed metadata navigation and a couple carefully designed lists & libraries.

I successfully created a custom page layout, which I used to create a single page. That page is the Target Page for my navigation term set, and it has one (for now) web part zone.

Ideally, I'd like to use the native list View functionality for my single document library as well as a couple other lists I'll be creating.

Then I'd leverage that view on the Target Page to display only the entries in the View that are relevant to the current Navigation Term.

I'm finding it easy to filter some web parts by the current navigation term, but not all web parts have that feature built in. I can use the Search Results, Items Matching a Tag, Content Query, or Content Search web parts just fine, since they have built-in capabilities to filter or refine by the current term.

While I'm *okay* with using one of those options, they all have drawbacks that the regular list view doesn't have, such as allowing end users to filter & sort results easily and customizing displayed fields without creating custom display templates.

Is there any way to leverage the built-in Filter web parts to utilize the current Navigation Term? I've been trying to figure out a way to do this for a few days, and I'm running out of hair to pull out.

**Update**

In the end, I believe the answer is "you can't do this without writing a custom filter web part." Since I didn't want to write & maintain that, I ended up deciding to use a Search Results web part instead. I was able to combine the result order dropdown and the Search Refiners web part to accomplish everything I could have done with the standard library view.

Comment: Same problem here. The problem with search results web part is that it doesn't include things like star ratings and every single thing needs to go through indexing. Anybody?